# Установка темы во время выполнения программы

Tags: email, java, javamail, log4j

```
### mail ###
log4j.category.EMailLog=ERROR, mail
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smpthost.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=mysite@site.ru
log4j.appender.mail.To=mymail@mail.tu
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Site Error
log4j.appender.mail.threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

В коде вызывается так:

```
private static final Logger EmailLogger = Logger.getLogger("EMailLog");
EmailLogger.error(string_message);
```

На почту приходит сообщение с subject, что в настройках. Вопрос: как его поменять динамически?

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотите иметь в поле subject? Можно, например, запихать туда прямо само сообщение. Тогда выставьте в настройках

```
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Site error: %m
```

Допустимые значения:

- %m
- %s
- %x
- [есть ещё другие](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Вообще, вы неверно используете логгеры. Обычно логгерам дают имена исходя из компоненты приложения, а не из способа логгирования. В этом весь смысл.

**UPD** Вероятно, вам надо логгерам давать имена вроде MainPage. А в паттерн вбить что-то типа Site error: %c

Comment: Например, subject хочу заменить на "Site Error - Main Page" или "Site Error - User Page".